# ExpressiveAnnotations works for Add View, but not Edit View MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, savechanges, expressiveannotations

In my metadata.cs file this works for when I hit _db.SaveChanges() in my AddRecord Controller Action. "[AssertThat(" works for Add SaveChanges(), but not for Edit SaveChanges().
"[Required]" works for both. "sss" won't pass on Add SaveChanges(), it will pass on Edit SaveChanges().

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
[AssertThat("IsEmail(Email)",ErrorMessage="Valid email format required")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

To explain in other words:
In EditRecord Controller Action only normal DataAnnotation fires, and not the [ExpressiveAnnotations](https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations) which I installed and works really good with conditional annotating. The Add and Edit Actions are both in same controller. And both use the Overide SaveChanges() when stepping through code, the Edit Action breaks on last line of the override and displays what is wrong in the error, but doesn't display ErrorMessage under the input like the Add View SaveChanges() does.

```
   public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                    .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

            // Join the list to a single string.
            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

            // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

            // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
```

This last line is where Edit Action stops with error:

```
throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
```

I got the above exception loop and override by studying StackOverflow, thank you very much, and it does capture the ExpressiveAnnotations error when email doesn't fit a valid format, but it chokes with Yellow Screen of Death. My Add Action doesn't choke and continues on as it should after record is added or rejected.

I hope I have given enough information. I looked at both views and they are virtually identical.

**couple hours later**

I thought maybe I'm not sending in the right model from the view when calling the Actions.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult EditStoreAccount(int id, FormCollection formValues)
{

    var accountToUpdate = _db.StoreAccounts.First(m => m.AccountID == id);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
//fill up accountToUpdate

 _db.SaveChanges();
```

And here is how I do the Add Action:

```
       [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult AddStoreAccount(StoreAccounts storeaccounts)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            _db.StoreAccounts.Add(storeaccounts);

{
            _db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, your gonna shoot me. Maybe not. I tried something and it worked.
My regular DataAnnotations were working for Edit View input validation like: [Required], [StringLength], and [RegularExpression]. ... but not for ExpressiveAnnotations like [RequiredIf] and [AssertThat].

The SaveChanges() override was the same for both Add and Edit except that ModelState.IsValid was not being filled with ExpressiveAnnotation errors for Edit Save action.

So. . . since the Add was sending in the Model, I decided to add the Model to the parameters coming into the Edit action:.

**Add**

```
public ActionResult AddStoreAccount(StoreAccounts storeaccounts)
```

**Edit**

```
public ActionResult EditStoreAccount(int id, FormCollection formValues, StoreAccounts storeaccounts)
```

Now, I didn't do nuthin' with the Model coming in (StoreAccounts storeaccounts). The MetaData class saw it and filled the ModelState so IsValid was false. And then it went on to put the error message(s) below the inputs just like regular DataAnnotations and no YSOD.

Oh, it's been a long hard journey figuring this MVC stuff out. They want so bad to make it like MS Access and/or Ruby LOL but they haven't quite got there yet.

I'm hoping this 10 hours of hair pulling will help someone else out on StackOverflow. Maybe someone could comment and explain what happened. Please feel free to comment. I seek enlightenment. If someone wants to make a more concise answer explaining this conundrum, I will gladly select their answer.